Sorting of nomenclature not right regarding upper and lowercase: sorting over prefix
When i try to make a nomenclature and sort i through prefix, i have the problem that first upper case letters are shown then lowercase and then upercase again: Bin < bin < BIo but i want it Bin < BIo < bin.
For example (MWE):
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[prefix]{nomencl} % Erzeugen von Nomenklatur mit Hilfe der *nlo Datei
%\renewcommand*{\nomprefix}{-}
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}
test
\nomenclature[Bin]{\(B_\mathrm{in}\)}{Test}
\nomenclature[bin]{\(b_\mathrm{in}\)}{Test}
\nomenclature[bio]{\(b_\mathrm{io}\)}{Test}
\nomenclature[BIn]{\(B_\mathrm{In}\)}{Test}
\nomenclature[bIn]{\(b_\mathrm{In}\)}{Test}
\nomenclature[BIn]{\(B_\mathrm{In}\)}{Test}
\nomenclature[BIo]{\(B_\mathrm{Io}\)}{Test}
\printnomenclature{}
\end{document}

Result:

What am i doing wrong?
Update:
 \nomenclature[-Bin]{\(B_\mathrm{in}\)}{Test}
 \nomenclature[-bin]{\(b_\mathrm{in}\)}{Test}
 \nomenclature[-bio]{\(b_\mathrm{io}\)}{Test}
 \nomenclature[-BIn]{\(B_\mathrm{In}\)}{Test}
 \nomenclature[-bIn]{\(b_\mathrm{In}\)}{Test}
 \nomenclature[-BIn]{\(B_\mathrm{In}\)}{Test}
 \nomenclature[-BIo]{\(B_\mathrm{Io}\)}{Test}

works fine:

but i use the first character for sorting it into different categories like "Latin", "Greek",... etc.

I'm afraid that this is how makeindex does the sorting.

@egreg as soon as i add an "-" in front of every prefix the sorting works fine. But i have over 1000 nomenclature entries and i use the  prefix for sorting into Latin Symbols, greek letters etc.
